# Getting arrayindexoutofboundsexception while running counting non-duplicate sub str operation

Tags: java, error-handling

I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while running below code. I am trying to calculate total number of non-duplicate sub string values in a string. I added try catch to stop this exception. Mostly i am getting in line `s2[j]=s2[k];`.

```
public class SubStrLen2 {
    public static int StrLen1(String s) {
        int n = s.length();
        int count=0, flag=0;
        char[] s1 = s.toCharArray();
        char[] s2 = s1;
       // char[] s3;
        for(int i=0; i<=n;i++)
        {
                for(int j =0;j<i; j++)
                {
                    if(s1[i] == s2[j])
                    {
                        if(i!=j) {
                        flag = 1;
                        for(int k=j+1;k<=n;k++,j++)
                        {
                            s2[j]=s2[k];
                        }
                        break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(flag==0)
                {
                    //s3[i]=s1[i];
                    count ++;
                }
                flag =0;        
                }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sc = "GreekGods";
        try {
        System.out.println("Length of the Sub str"+ StrLen1(sc));
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in Array");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i<=n should be i<n. In for loop. for(int i=0; i<n;i++)

Comment: and `k<=n` should be `k<n`

Comment: This helped, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple observation, a loop index start with 0 should end at **total length  -1**, so If n is your length of Array you code be should be

```
  for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
```

the same problem is at

```
for(int k=j+1;k<=n;k++,j++)
```

here you are not only using **=** sign which will cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, but you are also **incrementing j**, which is part of parent loop unless it is intended, you might not get the desired result.

Comment: what about `for(int k=j+1;k<=n;k++,j++)` ?

Comment: just overlooked that, thanks for reminding, editing the answer